# Allocate data on memory region

Tags: allocate, memory

I have initilized a PDA with 10000 bytes of space and a Vector on its stored data:

```
#[derive(Accounts, Clone)]
pub struct CreateVectorPda<'info> {
    /// CHECK: Just testing
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    /// CHECK: Just testing
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    #[account(init, payer=payer, space = 10000 , seeds = [b"seeds".as_ref()], bump)]
    vector_pda: Account<'info, VectorPDA>,

}
#[account]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct VectorPDA {
    pub addresses: Vec<Pubkey>,
    pub bump: u8,
}
```

But I cant store as much data as I want. For what I have researched yet, this happens because I am using Vec::push() on the vector stored in the account's data and, as the push method allocates the entire account's state I get the Error: memory allocation failed, out of memory.

This is my function for testing, just a loop trying to store 100 pubkeys in the vector each time the function is called.

```
pub fn populate_vector(ctx: Context<PopulateVector>) -> Result<()> {
        for i in 0..100 {
            ctx.accounts
                .vector_pda
                .addresses
                .push(ctx.accounts.payer.key())
        }
        Ok(())
    }

#[derive(Accounts, Clone)]
pub struct PopulateVector<'info> {
    /// CHECK: Just testing
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    /// CHECK: Just testing
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    #[account(mut, seeds = [b"seeds".as_ref(), bump = reveal_pda.bump)]
    vector_pda: Account<'info, VectorPDA>,
}
```

I have been told to use Vec::copy_from_slice() but cant figure how to get this data after storing it.

```
const SIZE1: usize = 13;
const SIZE2: usize = 45;

let data_ref: &mut [u8] = &mut ctx.accounts.pda_account.try_borrow_mut_data()?;
let account_to_store: [u8; 32] = ctx.accounts.account_to_store.key().to_bytes();
let data = data_ref.get_mut(SIZE1..SIZE2).unwrap();
data.copy_from_slice(&account_to_store);
```

The question is, how can I allocate data on an specific memory region instead of using Vec::push?
Do I need to desirialize the account first in order to access memory region?

Thanks.

Comment: can you elaborate what you've tried and the problems you've encountered with `copy_from_slice`?

Comment: Sure, I have tried this. I think this stores the public key: const SIZE1: usize = 13; const SIZE2: usize = 45; let data_ref: &mut [u8] = &mut ctx.accounts.pda_account.try_borrow_mut_data()?; let account_to_store: [u8; 32] = ctx.accounts.account_to_store.key().to_bytes(); let data = data_ref.get_mut(SIZE1..SIZE2).unwrap(); data.copy_from_slice(&account_to_store);

Answer (score 2):

A vector with a borsh account is intensive as on deserialization it copies all the existing data into the `VectorPda` `addresses` field and allocate a Pubkey for each element.

If you need to handle a large data structure and want to avoid large copies, read/write, you need to use Anchor `zero copy`.

It does not support `Vec<T>` but you can approximate the same behaviour using an array `[Pubkey; MAX_LEN]`
This will allow you to append and access elements without triggering a lot of overhead on serialization/deserialization.

Unfortunately, this isn't yet included in the Anchor book but you can learn how to use it thanks to the zero copy tests.

`EventQ` can contain up to 25,000 Event structs
https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/tests/zero-copy/programs/zero-copy/src/lib.rs#L156-L165